# Properties of Heaviside Function

Tags: step-function

Let $H(x)$ be the Heaviside function defined by

\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x\geq0\\
0 & \text{if } x<0
\end{cases}

I know that

1. $H'(x)=\delta(x)$. The derivative of the Heaviside function is the delta function.
2. $\delta(x)=\delta(-x)$. The delta function is symetric.

Does

1. $H(x)=H(-x)$?
2. $H(x)=-H(x)$?

It appears that

$$ -\delta(x)\delta(-y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$$

and

$$ -\delta(-x)\delta(y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$$

Do both of these properties follow from the definition of the Heaviside function?

Comment: $\delta (x) $ isn't an ordinary but generalised function so, you always need test function for proof of it's properties .i don't see how heaviside function helps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $H(x)=1-H(-x)$ for $x\ne 0$. Integrating something even gives something odd plus an integration constant.

Comment: And indeed, differentiating that using $H'(x) = \delta(x)$ gives the correct $\delta(x) = \delta(-x)$.

Comment: I see that, can this justify that $-\delta(x)\delta(-y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$?

Comment: @Axion004 Since $\delta$ is even, the leftmost $-$ sign shouldn't be there.

Comment: That is the part which is confusing to me. As $\delta(-y)=\delta(y)$, we have that $-\delta(x)\delta(-y)=-\delta(x)\delta(y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$. I don't see why $-\delta(x)\delta(y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$.

Comment: @Axion004 Where did you get the "it appears that" equations from?

Comment: I saw that $-H'(x)H'(-y) =\delta(x)\delta(y)$ and concluded that $-H'(x)H'(-y) =-\delta(x)\delta(-y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$.

Comment: @Axion004 Ah, I see; I think you went from the first equation to the second by replacing $y$ with $-y$, but forgot that $H^\prime (-y)=H^\prime(y)$ rather than $-H^\prime(y)$.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks!